# location of session data in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session-variables

i am doing a project in asp.net. it uses a login feature which i have implemented with 2 textboxes and a button. nothing fancy.

so now i have to distinguish which kind of user is logged in as there are different roles like admin, user, guest...

so what i need to know is what Session["UserAuthentication"] is and what it does...i think that i can add this data to an extra table to log all the sessions...is this a good approach?

here is my authentication method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = tbUsername.Text;
            string pwd = tbPassword.Text;
            string s;
            s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
            con.Open();
            string sqlUserName;
            sqlUserName = "SELECT Username, UserPassword FROM Benutzer WHERE Username ='" + username + "' AND UserPassword ='" + pwd + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, con);
            string CurrentName;
            CurrentName = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (CurrentName != null)
            {
                Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
                Session.Timeout = 1;
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblStatus.Text = "Benuztername/Password ungültig!";                               
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi man. WTF? `sqlUserName = "SELECT Username, UserPassword FROM Benutzer WHERE Username ='" + username + "' AND UserPassword ='" + pwd + "'";` -> so you wish someone to delete your DB right?

Comment: aside of your question, i'll suggest to encrypt you passwords to store in DB

Comment: is this code prone to sql injections?

Comment: It's like the best example of how to enable sql injections.

Comment: ok lol i am fairly new to databases...so i read that sanitizing input, using stored procedures and using parameters are good ways to prevent this...but is there like a class which checks for sql syntax or something like this? i am a little too lazy to do it with regular expressions or the like^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Session["UserAuthentication"]` is a variable that will hold the value of `username` globally across all pages for that particular current user.

Yes, you can add the data in a `SQL Table`. For that you need to add this in your `web.config` file.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=yourDataSource;user id=username;password=password" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

> Just in case if your are wondering where in `Database` does the `SessionId` of the variable is stored - for that you need to install the `ASPState Database` on your Server. And pass the connection string accordingly on the `web.config` file as described above.
>
> How to add the Database ASPState??
>   1. Go to this path: **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**
>   2. Here you will find a `script` named `InstallSqlState.sql` which you need to execute in your `SQL server`.

Comment: does it matter what i write in the brackets? i cant seem to find a list of defined variables. so i can just create my own set of variables and store them in the db?

Comment: ok thanks for the tips. do i have to use the ASPState Database or can i store session variables within my existing database?

Comment: Correct you can store anything you want in Session and name it anything.

Comment: you will have to use ASPState DataBase...just run the script that i have mentioned above which will create a database for you automatically..its harmless...u can experiment with it and learn more...u dun have to do anything more...just run the script and add the sessionstate in web.config file. Also mark it as answered if you have got your answer so that it mite help others.

Comment: ok one more thing: how do i run the script? i have found it, but i cant seem to find out how to run it. i am using sql server epress, if that matters.

Comment: m not entirely sure if it will run on Express edition...to run the script...just drag the script on your query window and Exectute it